# variable initialization in constructor not fast enough to prevent nullpointer exception in htmlcode [Angular]

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to initialize a variable based on an injected variable of type `any`.
But this doesn't happen in time because on the frontend the code:

```
<h2>{{(formGroup) ? formGroup.get('title').value : bookLinkArticle.title}}</h2>
```

causes a nullpointer exception.

Here is the code on the backend:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { GenericArticleDTO } from '../dto/generic-article-dto';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-book-article',
  templateUrl: './book-article.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./book-article.component.css']
})
export class BookArticleComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() data: any;
  bookLinkArticle: GenericArticleDTO;
  formGroup: FormGroup;

  //als het als voorbeeld gebruikt wordt moet de formGroup geinjecteerd worden, anders een bookLinkArticle.
  constructor() {
    if(this.data instanceof FormGroup){
      this.formGroup = this.data as FormGroup;
      console.log("is formgrpu undefined:" + this.formGroup === undefined);
    }
    else if(this.data instanceof GenericArticleDTO)
      this.bookLinkArticle = this.data as GenericArticleDTO;
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I've Always been under the impression that during object or component creation the constructor gets called first. According to the article [Essential difference between constructor and ngoninit](https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-essential-difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit-in-angular-c9930c209a42) this actually is the case. (You can read about it under the headlines *Difference related to the component initialization process*).

But it seems that the HTML template is constructed before the constructor is called, or else i wouldn't be getting a nullpointer exception. The solution is to move the code from the constructor to ngOnInit. But that just doesn't make sense to me, ngOnInit is a special method, but still a method and methods don't get called until after the constructor finished constructing/initializing. Because moving the code to ngOnInit solves the problem it almost seems as if ngOninit is called before the constructor is!

Can someone please explain to me what is going on here? Thank you

Comment: Perhaps `this.data` is not set yet in the constructor, so the constructor isn't doing anything?

Comment: I think constructor fires earlier then @input but on your place i'd better put that interpolation into a function that returns value that you need, and didn't run this fucntion nowhere except template.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen the component only loads when it has `data`. (i use *ngIf for that)

Comment: Even so, I don't see any way Angular can set `this.data` before calling the constructor.  I assume what Angular does is call the constructor, then set `this.data`, then call `ngOnInit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to get data as Input which is collected from a parent. So it will not be part of the constructor. It should be from Init

this link explains you clearly
https://toddmotto.com/angular-constructor-ngoninit-lifecycle-hook